# What is the word for something that makes you resentful or indignant?

Tags: word-choice

Let's someone treated me badly. He broke my cup on purpose, and I am indignant at that. How to describe that behaviour that caused me to be indignant? Can I say that that person's behaviour is bitter?

Comment: There are far too many words that could fit here. You will need to be more focused in what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ***bitter*** does mean:

> something that causes deep pain or anger ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bitter))

it is not idiomatic to characterise someone's *behaviour* as *bitter*. I am not very sure  why, but my feeling is that the noun characterised as *bitter* more often than not provokes bitterness in the person possessing it, not in someone else. Some of the [most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bitter%20%2A_NOUN%2C%20bitter%20behaviour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cbitter%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbitter%20taste_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20experience_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20tears_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20disappointment_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20almonds_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20end_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20cup_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20enemies_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20enemy_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbitter%20cold_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbitter%20behaviour%3B%2Cc0) nouns used with *bitter* are *taste, tears, disappointment*.

For example: *bitter taste* is a taste which is bitter to the person who is experiences the taste, it does not provoke bitterness in another person. The same goes for *bitter tears* (you cannot say that *your tears are bitter for me*) and for *bitter disappointment* (you cannot say that *your disappointment causes bitterness in me*).

You could use ***embittering***, which comes from the transitive verb *embitter* and works grammatically, but only if you want to emphasise the idea of resentment. *Embittering* means:

> having qualities that make a person feel bitter ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/embittering))

In *bitter*, the idea of rancour seems stronger than anger.

A better word choice in order to emphasise the idea of anger would be ***infuriating*** which means:

> extremely annoying:
>
> - It's infuriating when people keep spelling your name wrong, isn't it? ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infuriating))

Certainly, any [synonyms of ***annoying***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/annoying.html) would work too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Aggravating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggravating)

But I can think of a few other words too, such as:

Bothersome
Irritating
Vexatious

But I don't think *Bitter* would be the correct term. In fact you would be more likely to be the one who is bitter in this case.